# How much Vitamin E is safe to take on long-term for a male young adult?

Tags: micronutrients, vitamin-e

I have [read](http://www.efsa.europa.eu/sites/default/files/efsa_rep/blobserver_assets/ndatolerableuil.pdf) that the European Food Safety Authority has established an upper limit of 270 mg/day.

> The UL for vitamin E was therefore established as 270 mg/day for adults
>   and rounded to 300 mg/day.

Comment: Vitamin RDA depends on variables such as age and sex. Still, we can't personalise your supplementation, since personal medical questions are off-topic. If you [edit] your question to link some of your research and have a specific (but not personal) question, we might answer that.

Comment: I edited the question. I am interested in the upper limit.